# Samsung Easy document Scanner won't communicate with scanner on OS X Catalina 10.15

Tags: catalina, scanning

After upgrading to Catalina OSX 10.15 Easy Document Creator can no longer connect to the remote scanner. It shows up within settings and can be addressed directly but not over the EDC software anymore.

The error reads:

"Scanner device is not responding. Please check that it is turned on and connected to computer".

[image] 
Easy Printer Manager though shows the printer and its toner level etc.

Is there any fix for this? I know that Scan Assistent is 32 bit but that software was not needed anymore and OSX did not complain about EDC so in theory it should work.

In Samsung Easy Printer Manager also if I try to change the settings I get "Current input language cannot be accepted for device. Please change input language"

Answer (score 4):

That is because Easy Document Creator uses several apps underneath and not all are 64-bit, as required by Catalina.

One of them is Select Scanner.app (in /Applications/Samsung/Samsung Easy Document Creator.app/Contents/Resources/Select Scanner.app), which is 32-bit for Intel and PowerPC (!).

The other one, with the same problem, is ICCUpdater.

There's nothing you can do; only bug HP to publish updated version.

Meanwhile, to be able to scan at all, use Image Capture or Preview (File, Import...). Just make sure that the scanned file is OK, the Apple drivers seem to be broken too; for example, I cannot scan in color into PDF, the resulting PDF is broken (Samsung M2070w). B/W PDF is fine, so is color JPG.

Answer (score -1):

**Re-create Bluetooth plist file on Mac**

1. Open **Finder** on Mac. Next, **Go** > **Go to Folder** > type “**/Library/Preferences/**” and Open.
2. Find, **com.apple.Bluetooth.plist** file and **Delete** it.

[image]

3. Now, Reboot your Mac to refresh Bluetooth settings.

Above mentioned solutions have worked 99% of the case.

Let me know how it goes for you.

Comment: Why Bluetooth? The printer/scanner is connected via WiFi.

Comment: Have you tried it? It will not impact anything. Try and see it. Previously it was working and after the update it is not working, isn't it ?

Comment: No, there is no such file in existence. Just those:

com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist
com.apple.Bluetooth.133E3777-20D1-5B7E-BC1C-FFCEC5F80E85.plist
com.apple.Bluetooth.CE17D42D-E98F-52A3-9260-D8E0139918C0.plist
com.apple.Bluetooth.C175C084-1410-5A70-977E-CA1F718CB797.plist
com.apple.BluetoothFileExchange.plist
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse.plist